# Setting MIME Content Type With Golang and Google Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, go, blobstore

I followed this post and got the example code uploading a Blobstore object.

[Is it possible to store arbitrary data in GAE Golang Blobstore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144066/is-it-possible-to-store-arbitrary-data-in-gae-golang-blobstore/20396827#20396827)

However the content-type is set to application/octet-stream

Does anyone have any idea how I would go about modifying that code to send a image/jpg content-type?

Comment: Shouldn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20147721/5125201) answer solve your question?

Comment: That answer must be using a very old API. 

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/reference

There is no Create Method currently.